# How to configure the indexer so that "word1.word2" is considered as two words

Tags: java, indexing, lucene

supose a file 'test.txt' being indexed, the content of file is:

```
word1.word2
```

what should I do to make lucene consider "word1.word2" as two words "word1" and "word2" not "word1.word2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on which `Analyzer` you are using. The short generic answer would be to use a `SimpleAnalyzer` that uses a `LetterTokenizer`. The `LetterTokenizer` splits at any non-letter, thus including the dot character.
If you have more specific tokenization requirements you must code a custom Analyzer class whose `tokenStream` method returns a custom [TokenStream](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/TokenStream.html) or [Tokenizer](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Tokenizer.html) object.

Answer (score 1):

Lucene indexing with an analyzer will convert your words into Tokens of terms,(technically it converts the words into fields forming a document)

basically you can

1) create a StopAnalyzer and pass a HashSet with stop word as *"."(period)* this can have adverse effect on indexing(since [you must use same analyzer while searching and indexing](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#Why_is_it_important_to_use_the_same_analyzer_type_during_indexing_and_search.3F))

2) split the . with space and index them